# 4k HDMI output with Intel HD graphics/Nvidia

Tags: hdmi, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card, 4k-resolution

I would like to use a Ultra HD external monitor/TV over HDMI, but the problem is that the maximum offered resolution is Full HD (with output set to External display only).

I am running Windows 8.1 on a Fujitsu LIFEBOOK NH532 laptop, with the following specs: i7 3610QM (Intel HD Graphics 4000), 8GB RAM and an NVIDIA GT 640M LE 2GB graphic card. According to [this page](http://ultrabooknews.com/2012/10/31/new-intel-hd-3000-and-hd-4000-drivers-support-for-windows-8-4k-ultra-hd-opengl-4-0-and-more/), newest Intel drivers should support 4K resolutions. NVidia's specs [also state 3840 x 2160](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-640m-le) as the "maximum digital resolution".

But all the menus I've found related to display resolution seem to indicate that only the Intel's adapter is the one transmitting the data through - NVidia's control panel doesn't even mention resolutions anywhere, and they offer Full HD as the max resolution. The thing with NVidia on laptops is also their ["Optimus technology"](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/optimus), meaning that it sits doing nothing most of the time, and only actually running for intensive games.

I have connected the laptop to a HDMI 2.0 input, certainly capable of receiving 4k (even at 60Hz). Is there something I should configure to make this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDMI 2.0 is fairly uncommon on PCs even now - my 980ti was one of the earlier video cards to support it, and most video outs from older machines are HDMI 1.2/3.

While the GPU itself is 4k ready, the outputs may not be - I've worked with a 4K capable display with a video card of roughly similar vintage (a 660) and the only 4k capable output was displayport.

I've found even where a higher respolution may be supported, the fallback for many UHD displays is 1080p, and you might need to do some messing around to try to get something like QHD working.

Comment: It's been a year since this post, but IIRC it turned out that this HDMI port was only accessible to the Intel integrated card. This forced me to use resolution independent rendering from the very start anyway, so I worked with 4k (on a different machine) and 1080p interchangeably all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You laptop probably only has HDMI 1.3 out though, so you'd be limited to 30hz, is HDMI your only option?

in any case just try disable optimus somewhere, that may do the trick, otherwise you could try a clean install with the newest drivers?

Also might be time for a new laptop meng.

Comment: What is a meng?

Comment: It's been more than a year, so it doesn't matter anymore, but it turned out to be a 1.3 HDMI port, yes. Not even connected to the nvidia card, but only to i7. Ironically, latest nvidia drivers (installed through windows update) screwed up this laptop's win8 installation so badly I had to reinstall everything.